# PHP with regex replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty new to regex so I want to ask a problem related to it. Basically I want to change only value part of an JSON string with certain key.
Currently i am using For example :
`{ "id":1, "newId":2,..."age":20}`. 
I need to replace both of "id" and "newId"'s value to something like `{"id":encrypt(1),"newId":encrypt(2)...,"age":20}`.
 How can I achieve that in PHP using regex ? Thank in advance.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Not that you should use regex for this, parse the JSON instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry for not clarify enough, I can solve the problem with normal coding by replacing string, but the code is a mess so I'm thinking about using regex to easier to maintain. I read about named group in regex but can't figure out how to use them in this case.

Comment: Using regex when you already have JSON will make things *more* unnecessarily complicated, not less.

Comment: Parse the JSON in my case won't work well as the key can be hidden deep inside child objects and the JSON is not always from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a value inside a `json` object as follows:

```
$json = json_decode('{ "id":1, "newId":2, "age":20}', true);
$json['id'] = 11;
$json['newId'] = 22;
print_r($json);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 11
    [newId] => 22
    [age] => 20
)
```

---

**Notes:**

1. [PHP Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QIp)
2. [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)